# systemd-networkd won't reload virtual network interface configuraion file

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to configure a tap interface using systemd-networkd configuration files.
I created the files:

```
/etc/systemd/network/tap_test.network
/etc/systemd/network/tap_test.netdev
```

with the contents:

```
tap_test.network:
[Match]
Name=tap_test

[Network]
Description=TEST tap interface
Address=192.168.2.100

tap_test.netdev:
[Match]

[NetDev]
Name=tap_test
Kind=tap
```

Then in restarted the `systemd-networkd` service:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

As expected, running `ifconfig` shows the new tap interface. HOWEVER, when I tried to alter the ip address in the configuration file `tap_test.network` to end with `101`, then tried to restart the `systemd-networkd` once again, no change coul'd be seen when I ran `ifconfig` again (the ip address remains the old one).

I also tried to shut down the interface with `ifconfig tap_test down` and then restart the service, it didn't help either.

How can I make systemd-networkd reload the configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

To quote [systemd.netdev(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html#Description):

> Virtual network devices are created as soon as networkd is started. If
>   a netdev with the specified name already exists, networkd will use
>   that as-is rather than create its own. Note that the settings of the
>   pre-existing netdev will not be changed by networkd.

So, apparently, this is so by design. I think you need to find a way to deallocate the tap device by yourself (if this is at all possible) and add the required commands to `ExecStopPost=` of `systemd-networkd.service` unit.

You can use drop-ins for the latter.

`/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/tuntap.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStopPost=<your command goes here>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ifdown tap_test` and `ifup tap_test` instead of `ifconfig`.

Point being that `ifup` do some more work. `ifconfig` is bare minimum.

`ifup ethX` uses the config file and bring up interface with correct IP address etc.

`ifconfig ethX up` only starts the interface.

Comment: It would be nice to give some explanation as to why that should help.

Comment: @peterph: Yes. I tried to leave as comment first, but <50rep. Anyhow: I also miss-read from Q *"... `ifconfig tap_test down` and then restart the service ..."* – I somehow read that he used ifconfig to take it up as well. Not sure what the service process, but *guess* it read same as `ifup` or perhaps even wrapper for it. IDK. Added some more detail any how.